# ASP.net 2010 (VB) Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Morning All,

I am using VS2010 with VB and im trying to get a ping test working in my web application. In order to do this and test that it works i have simply created a button that when clicks should ping a specified IP address.

I believe that the code for the button should work fine.  The only issue i have is the following error message on my web page...

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

It bugs on the cole line...

```
Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}", vPingReply.Address)
```

I thought that this was due to 'Properties' needing to be set up for the .Address and .Status objects.  Im not too sure if i have added these correctly as i have added some properties but i still have the same issue when i run the page?

Can someone please take a look and advise?

Here is my full code...

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply


Partial Class Ping
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private mSend As PingReply

Private Property Send(p1 As String) As PingReply
    Get
        Return mSend
    End Get
    Set(value As PingReply)
        mSend = value
    End Set
End Property


Private mAddress As PingReply

Private Property Address(p2 As String) As PingReply
    Get
        Return mAddress
    End Get
    Set(value As PingReply)
        mAddress = value
    End Set
End Property

Private mStatus As PingReply

Private Property Status(p3 As String) As PingReply
    Get
        Return mStatus
    End Get
    Set(value As PingReply)
        mStatus = value
    End Set
End Property


Protected Sub btnPing_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPing.Click
    Dim vPing As New Ping
    Dim vPingReply As PingReply = vPing.Send("xxx.xx.xxx.xx")
    Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}", vPingReply.Address)
    Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", vPingReply.Status)
End Sub

End Class
```

Any help is much appriechiated.

Betty.

Comment: If you check the value of "vPingReply.Address" in debug, is it set to anything?

Comment: @Jacooobley, i have debuged the page and the vPing.Send and vPingReply both = nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the content of Address property if the Status is not Success

```
Dim vPing As New Ping
Dim vPingReply As PingReply = vPing.Send("xxx.xx.xxx.xx")
if vPingReply.Status = IPStatus.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}", vPingReply.Address)
End If
Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", vPingReply.Status)
```

The docs says

> If the value of Status is not Success, you should not use the values
>   returned by the RoundtripTime, Options or Buffer properties. The
>   RoundtripTime property will return zero, the Buffer property will
>   return an empty array, and the Options property will return null.

but I found that the Address property is null (Nothing in VB) also if the Send is for a non-existant ip address or DNS name

However, looking better at your code, it is clear that all the calls made inside the btnPing_Click method are handled by your class Ping not to the framework class Ping. And your class uses variables not correctly initialized. I suggest to remove those methods from your class  or just rename the class with something different.
Another option (not recommended) is this

```
Private Property Send(p1 As String) As PingReply
    Get
        ' Specify the full namespace to remove ambiguity between this class and framework class
        Dim p = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping()
        mSend = p.Send(p1)
        Return mSend
    End Get
    Set(value As PingReply)
        mSend = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Property Address() As String
    Get
        if mSend IsNot Nothing Then
            Return mSend.Address
        else
            Return string.Empty
        End If
    End Get
    ' Meaningless ???
    'Set(value As PingReply)
    '    mAddress = value
    'End Set
End Property

Private mStatus As PingReply

Private Property Status() As String
    Get
        if mSend IsNot Nothing Then
            Return mSend.Status.ToString()
        else
            Return string.Empty
        End If
    End Get
    ' Meaningless ???
    'Set(value As PingReply)
    '    mStatus = value
    'End Set
End Property
```

Comment: i have included your suggestion for the If condition but the web page now bugs on the new line of code 'If vPingReply.Status = IPStatus.Success Then' with the same error message 'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.  It looks like the code isnt getting anything from the IP address i have.  However i know that this box is available as its our development box and i can successfully ping this from the the start menu and the cmd prompt?

Comment: Your class is named Ping. This means that when you call vPing.Send you call the Send property of your class not the Send method of the framework Ping class. Your property returns the mSend internal variable, but this variable is not initialized anywhere and thus, when you call Success it is like you write `Nothing.Success`

Comment: many thanks for your help.  I have changed the class name to PingDetails and the Inherits section on the aspx page.

Comment: That's the way to go for me.